# What does "$f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ on a compact interval" means?

Tags: definition

In some theorems, I see "$f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ on a compact interval". $[a,b]$ is actually compact, does this kind of emphasize have another meaning?

Edit for a comment: "A continuous function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ on a compact interval is Riemann integrable."

Comment: Could you quote some more context for that phrasing, please?

Comment: I edited with an example...

Comment: The edited comment still looks like it's a frament . The property is not true for all $f$ -- for example, the indicator function of $\mathbb Q\cap [a,b]$ is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to put it is continuous. By the way, what does frament mean? I couldn't find it in dictionary. (I am learning English too:) )

Comment: It was a typo for "fragment".

Comment: I think just emphasis.  Or giving it a name.  Say "compact" interval instead of "closed" interval because, technically, $[a,+\infty)$ is a "closed" set and you do not want to include this.

Comment: But we can't write $[a,\infty]$, right? or $[-\infty, b]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly just redundant emphasis: the phrase "on a compact interval" and writing the domain as $[a,b]$ are basically conveying the same information twice.

However, the phrase "on a compact interval" also clarifies that $[a,b]$ can be *any* compact interval and the claimed statement will hold.  If you leave it out, it might sound like you are referring to some *specific* interval $[a,b]$, where you have previously defined $a$ and $b$, and that it might not hold for more general compact intervals.

Comment: As I understood by comments too, there is no further meaning. Thanks for your answer.